# ide for debugging C++ project

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, netbeans, ide

I have downloaded rx. Can somebody please tell of a suitable ide for debugging and building the source code of "rdf-3x". As per the operating system: ubuntu & Windows are both fine for me.

I tried netbeans (C++) but it does not work for me, since it does not treat all the folders within as one project, rather it treats them as separate projects.

Comment: Which **OS**? And i think there are already far too many posts about IDEs in SO. Please search a little or just try them out...

Comment: @RedX Yes I saw those posts, but i am in particular searching for an ide for debugging "rdf-3x". Also I tried some of them, but of no use...ide's like netbeans does not treat "rdf-3x" as one project but rather considers them as different folders, and I am looking for an ide which treats the whole source code of "rdf-3x" as one project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Eclipse..

It's user friendly for me..
You can try it.
http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/

CMIIW

Comment: Thanks a ton for helping. I have installed eclipse on ubuntu but the problem that I am facing is..i am trying to open the project through open project...but since rdf-3x in google repository consists of multiple folders...therefore I am not able to open up the entire project. Please excuse my ignorance...if in case you know a solution for this..the please do tell...i'll be highly obliged for the same

Comment: I'm not so sure, but maybe moving it manually to 1 project can help..
CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking a look at [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)? Since you mentioned Ubuntu I am assuming that you need something which runs on Linux. If you are not, and are using Windows, you could take a look at [Dev C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html).

I have never used them extensively though, so I can't really provide more information that this.

Comment: Thanks a ton for helping. I have installed CodeBlocks on ubuntu but the problem that I am facing is..i am trying to open the project through open project...but since rdf-3x in google repository consists of multiple folders...therefore I am not able to open up the entire project. Please excuse my ignorance...if in case you know a solution for this..the please do tell...i'll be highly obliged for the same